# Delete markup block shortcut

Tags: webstorm

Is there posibility to delete block of code by one shortcut?

[image]

Also next question: is there posibility to delete only inner div content by shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there posibility to delete block of code by one shortcut?

Well ... make a selection that will include all that code and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> key (or whatever the key you may have configured there for generic `Delete` action).

---

To make selection of such stuff easier -- use `Edit | Extend Selection` few times in a row (<kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> on Windows/Linux using Default keymap and <kbd>Alt+ Up</kbd> on Mac).

You may also use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + ]</kbd> to quickly select whole tag (well -- from opening to closing angle bracket) ... but for that you must have your caret placed just before opening `<` symbol. In case if you have different shortcut in your keymap -- look for `Editor Actions | Move Caret to Code Block End with Selection` action at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`.

---

> Also next question: is there posibility to delete only inner div content by shortcut?

There is `Code | Unwrap/Remove...` .. but it works with outer content and not inner.

The only alternative I could think of right now (that I'm aware of) is to place caret just after opening `<div>` tag (using you code sample as an example) and invoke aforementioned `Edit | Expand Selection` to quickly select all inner content.